# Discriminate between bell states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Is it possible to discriminate between 2 of the four Bell states (phi, psi) and does it interfere with the entanglement?

Comment: What do you mean by "does it interfere with the entanglement"? -- Otherwise, these are two orthogonal states, so yes, it is possible to distinguish them with certainty.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious that Bell states are already entangled states.

Comment: My comment above were actually two independent comments: (i) Yes, it is possible to distinguish deterministically between Bell states. (ii) What do you mean by "does it interfere with the entanglement"? -- If you feel I just pointed out obvious things, then you should make your question more precise.

Comment: What I meant is that it became obvious to me after your comment that Bell states are already entangled and if one can distinguish them then they're still Bell states and still entangled. Just didn't think about the meaning of Bell states. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Happy to help; I have turned it into a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The four Bell states are orthogonal, so it is possible to distinguish all of them deterministically.  Of course, this requires joint measurements on both qubits.